# Hook_user to display a message on a page

Tags: 7, hooks

In Drupal 6, I would like to use hook_user to display a message using `drupal_set_message` following a user record `after_update`

This is all I have in my module, which I've enabled, but I think I may need something else?

```
function assigncoordinator_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
  drupal_set_message(t('111111'));
  switch($op) {
    case 'after_update':
      drupal_set_message(t('module is working'));
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this Drupal 6?

Comment: Sorry yes this is drupal 6

Comment: Cool, is it just that the `after_update` op isn't getting fired, or is your hook implementation never entered at all? Try sticking `drupal_set_message('test');` at the top of that function, then visit a user account page. If you don't see a message, it might be your module's not called `assigncoordinator`, or that you just need to clear the cache

Comment: Not really answer but I called the function assigncoordinator_user and when copy / pasting the name to the file names forgot to remove _user so it was reading assigncoordinator_user.module. Should I delete this question? as I am not sure it will help anyone

Comment: Are you suppressing messages, or are the messages being rendered but not shown following a redirect? Try an echo and an exit instead of drupal_set_message to verify.